# Bootstrap switch Toggle - One is on, the other is off using checkbox and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Help me for Bootstrap switch Toggle - One is on, the other is off using checkbox and jQuery.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="ios" data-size="normal" data-on="&#8203;" data-off="&#8203;" onclick="change_ins(1)" class="switch switch-on toggle" checked value="true" id="toggle1">
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="ios" data-size="normal" data-on="&#8203;" data-off="&#8203;" onclick="change_ins(2)" class="switch switch-off toggle" id="toggle2">
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="ios" data-size="normal" data-on="&#8203;" data-off="&#8203;" onclick="change_ins(3)" class="switch switch-off toggle" id="toggle3">
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="ios" data-size="normal" data-on="&#8203;" data-off="&#8203;" onclick="change_ins(4)" class="switch switch-off toggle" id="toggle4">
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="ios" data-size="normal" data-on="&#8203;" data-off="&#8203;" onclick="change_ins(5)" class="switch switch-off toggle" id="toggle5">
```

Comment: looks like you dont have much time to code , very precise, lets see when you start getting dowvoted

Comment: Please be precise with your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(".toggle123").change(function() { 
  var tid= this.id;
  
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $('.toggle123').each(function() {
    if(this.id != tid){ $("#"+this.id).bootstrapToggle('off'); }
});
      /* $(".toggle").bootstrapToggle('off');
   */
   
  } 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="ios" data-size="normal" data-on="&#8203;" data-off="&#8203;" class="switch switch-on toggle toggle123"  id="toggle1">
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="ios" data-size="normal" data-on="&#8203;" data-off="&#8203;" class="switch switch-off toggle toggle123" id="toggle2">

<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="ios" data-size="normal" data-on="&#8203;" data-off="&#8203;" class="switch switch-off toggle toggle123" id="toggle3">

<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="ios" data-size="normal" data-on="&#8203;" data-off="&#8203;" class="switch switch-off toggle toggle123" id="toggle4">

<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-style="ios" data-size="normal" data-on="&#8203;" data-off="&#8203;" class="switch switch-off toggle toggle123" id="toggle5">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Even though the answer was accepted, it would be useful for future users, if you included some text to explain why this ansers the Q